# powershell - is it possible to create a text file with header fields and align the fields of every inserted line with its corresponding header field?

Tags: powershell

I've made a powershell script that first creates a text file (providing it doesn't already exist) with a line containing 2 header fields, "NAME" and "SURNAME" separated by a few whitespaces.

It will then prompt the user to insert a name and a surname, both of which will be written as a new single line to the text file, underneath the header line. The user doesn't need to insert more name-surname lines but the idea is to create a few more of these lines.

However, I have no idea about how to align every inserted surname with the "SURNAME" header field. By "align" I mean the first letter of every surname be in the same column as the "S" of "SURNAME" (the explanation may not be necessary but just in case...)

Anyway, here's the code:

```
clear

[string]$name=read-host -prompt "Enter the name"
[string]$surname=read-host -prompt "Enter the surname"
[string]$header="NAME        SURNAME"
[string]$line="$name        $surname"

add-content -value $header -path c:\data.txt
add-content -value $line -path c:\data.txt
$answer=read-host -prompt "¿Would you like to keep inserting name-surname pairs? (yes/no)" 

while ($answer -eq "yes") {

  $name=read-host -prompt "Enter the name"
  $surname=read-host -prompt "Enter the surname"
  $line="$name       $surname"
  add-content -value $line -path c:\data.txt
  $answer=read-host -prompt "¿Would you like to keep inserting name-surname pairs? (yes/no)" 
}

get-content -path c:\data.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a format string:

```
'{0, -20}{1, -20}' -f $Name,$Surname
```

The first number in the curly braces is the index of the array element to insert.

The second is the column width.  A negative number will left justify, and a positive number will right justify, so that format string will left-justify $Name in a 20 character column, followed by $Surname left-justified in another 20 character column.  Adjust ingredients to suit.

Comment: so there's no need to cast $line as [array] instead of [string]?                 just redefine $line as "$line='{0, -20}{1, -20}' -f $name,$surname"?

Comment: Right.  Then add the line to your file, using Add-Content, or Out-File -Append.